# Kumuluzee JPA Persistence settings outside persistence unit

Tags: jpa, persistence, kumuluzee

We are trying to configure the [Kumuluz JPA](https://github.com/kumuluz/kumuluzee-samples/tree/master/jpa).

We would like to tailor the Persistence Unit programmatically and for that, we need a handle on the PersistenceUnit Properties. This is already pre-packaged inside the kumuluz jpa dependency and we have apparently no way of getting a handle on the properties at runtime.

Has anyone had the same problem of having to set the properties at runtime? Can you please share your methods?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access persistence.xml configuration in runtime, nor would it make any sense to do so, since persistence.xml is read by JPA provider only at the very beginning of the application start-up.

You can, however, configure persistence.xml during build time with maven configuration, by using [Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/). For example:

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <db.action>create</db.action>
  </properties>
  ...
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

**persistence.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="kumuluzee-samples-jpa" transaction-type="JTA">

        <jta-data-source>jdbc/CustomersDS</jta-data-source>

        <class>com.kumuluz.ee.samples.jpa.Customer</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="${db.action}"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: The question was about tailoring the PU properties and not the persistence unit constitution itself. If one looks into the JPA component of kumuluz, the code is written in a manner that allows us to read properties which are only within the XML. We need to change these programmatically based on some conditions. One can modify the JPA behavior when it creates EntityManager, by tailoring these properties. For example, what if an Entity manger needs to create tables in one invocation and only the db script in another? Like in: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bootstrap-jpa.

Comment: @VenkataRahulSatuluri The answer is exactly about the PU properties, not just persistence unit constitution. They cannot be changed during runtime. It sounds like you have an architectural problem and you're trying to solve it with a tool that isn't meant to solve it. Try asking a broader question.

Comment: Thank you. The question was not about changing at runtime after the EM is initiated but to set an EM's properties before it is instantiated. In certain cases, we want the Entity Manager to be created with specific settings such as a Custom Session manager or with a different logger. Thank you also for the comment on our architectural problem.